# Rails ternary operator and 'this'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ternary-operator

Does Rails have a `this` like javascript/Jquery does?

Take this example:

```
User.find_by_email(params[:candidate][:email].present? ? (u = this.id) : (u = 'not here')
```

or:

```
if User.find_by_email(params[:candidate][:email].present?
  a += 1
  user = this
end
```

I'm aware that this code might be rewritten in more efficient ways *in this case*, but my question is about being able to use `this`. Does Ruby have something like this?

Comment: `self` is Ruby's `this`. Although your code is confusing.

Comment: in js, this is about function context rather then having anything to do with operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of a class you use `self`.

In these cases though this code is not in `User` context so you have to make an assignment.

```
u = User.find_by_email(params[:candidate][:email])

user_name = u.any? ? u.name : 'not here'
```

I prefer `.any?` to `.present?` in this context as it reads better.

Comment: The `find_by_email` method will return an object OR `nil`. The `any?` method can be used on a array/hash enumerator. Your code will throw  `NoMethodError` error. I would use  ` User.find_by_email(params[:candidate][:email]).try(:name) || `not here` (assuming `name` field is never empty in an user object).

Answer (score 2):

Ruby uses `self` to denote `this`. I am not quite sure if you need to use `self` for your problems.

First scenario can be rewritten as:

```
u = User.find_by_email(params[:candidate][:email]).try(:id) || 'not here'
```

Second scenario can be rewritten as:

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:candidate][:email])
a += 1 if user.present?
```

Comment: I was just writing quick examples to try to illustrate the self-reference I was getting at. These examples aren't great code, I know! Thanks.

Comment: @sscirrus Don't hesitate to post the code. I am sure some one here will be able to answer the question to the point.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the more idiomatic ruby approach for your case would be something like the following:

```
User.where("email in (?)", email_arr).each do |user|
    a += 1
    user.foo = bar
end
```

but it's hard to say without seeing the all code.